# Finding out data dependencies in PySpark

Tags: python, database, apache-spark, pyspark, dependencies

I am working with a lot of tables in PySpark and I am looking for a way to get table/data dependencies of different tables.
What I mean is: for example I am saving a table A which is created by using multiple other tables (X, Y, Z). Now I want to save in another logfile the information that table A is created by using (X, Y, Z).

| Created Table | Used tables |
| --- | --- |
| A | [X, Y, Z] |
| B | [A] |

I would not need the information on how these tables are created (which kind of transformations etc.).

Do you know a way how to achieve this or any metadata which could help me here? Unfortunately dataframe.explain() does not give me the used table names.

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards

Paul

Comment: can you show how table A is created from tables X,Y,Z? you probably need a reference table that's updated whenever any table is created

Comment: # Some simplified approach
tableA = spark.table("tableA")
tableB = spark.table("tableB")

# some transformations on tableA & tableB 
...

# Creating tableC 

tableC = tableA.join(tableB, tableA.id = tableB.id, "left")

# Aggregation of some sort

tableC.write.partitionBy('partitionid').mode("overwrite").format("orc").saveAsTable("tableC")